# How to understand the definition of meromorphic function in "Complex Analysis" by Stein?

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

The points $\{z_0,z_1,z_2,\cdots\}$ don't belong to $\Omega$, do they?

$\{z_0,z_1,z_2,\cdots\}$ is a sequence of points, so we may have $z_i=z_j$ with $i\neq j$, is it right?

Comment: "The points $\{z_0,z_1,z_2,\cdots\}$ don't belong to $\Omega$, do they?" They do, very much so. "$\{z_0,z_1,z_2,\cdots\}$ is a sequence of points, so we may have $z_i=z_j$ with $i\neq j$, is it right?" We may, but this brings nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if the $\{z_i\}$ weren't in $\Omega$ the condition that $f$ be holomorphic on $\Omega - \{z_i\}$ would be just be saying that $f$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$.

A very simple example is $f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$ which is meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ and $\{z_i\} = \{0\}$.

As for your second question, it is unconventional to assume repetitions in the set notation, but theoretically we could. The important thing about this though is that for every point $z \in \Omega$ there is an open set $z \in V$ with $V \cap \{z_i\} = \emptyset$ that is what is meant by saying the set $\{z_i\}$ has no limit points in $\Omega$. Notice that having repetitions doesn't change this condition.